# How to retrieve single variable value in a struct

Tags: json, swift, struct

I use Post2 as a struct and a function GetTodaysProfit() to fetch JSON data from web.

```
struct Post2: Codable,Identifiable {
let id = UUID()
var totalasset: Double
var totaltodaysprofit: Double
var todaysprofitpercent: Double
var totalmarketvalue: Double
var maxpurchasepower: Double
}

func GetTodaysProfit(completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
    var ttlTodaysProfit: Double = 0.00
    let url = URL(string: getTotalsString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, _, _) in
    let postArray = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Post2].self, from: data!)
    if let post = postArray.first {
       ttlTodaysProfit = post.totaltodaysprofit
    }
    completion(ttlTodaysProfit)
    }
.resume()

}
```

The original JSON data contains only one row of these 5 Double values, I need to get each of them and put in separate Text Views in ContentView. How can I refer specific item in a struct? Or did I do anything wrong with this code?

Part code in ContentView:

```
 var pro = GetTodaysProfit { profit in
    return profit
}

Text(String(pro))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function is an asynchronous function, which means "return ttlTodaysProfit" is not going to return the result you expect.
Since you say there is only 1 row in the array you decode,
I suggest you try the following approach to return the result you want.

Edit:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Post2: Codable,Identifiable {
let id = UUID()
var totalasset: Double = 0.0
var totaltodaysprofit: Double = 0.0
var todaysprofitpercent: Double = 0.0
var totalmarketvalue: Double = 0.0
var maxpurchasepower: Double = 0.0
}

struct ContentView: View {
@State var post = Post2()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("\(self.post.totaltodaysprofit)")
        Text("\(self.post.totalasset)")
    }.onAppear(perform: loadData)
}

func loadData() {
    getTodaysPost() { todayPost in
        if let thePost = todayPost {
            self.post = thePost
        }
    }
}

func getTodaysPost(completion: @escaping (Post2?) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://example.com")  // <-- to be supplied
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, _, _) in
        let postArray = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Post2].self, from: data!)
        if let post = postArray.first {
            return completion(post)
        }
        completion(nil)
    }
    .resume()
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! The complaint is gone while using escaping closure. But as I am a new comer, I still can't put the value in Text View using the call function with closure. I used a var 'pro' to store the profit value, but it seem I can't just use Text("\(pro)"). I get this error message 

Type '()' cannot conform to '_FormatSpecifiable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols.

Furthermore, how  can I put say, totalasset and totaltodaysprofit, in two different Text Views? My apology if I ask dummy questions.

Comment: you need to give Text() a String. So try this: Text(String(pro)) etc... for the other var. Alternatively you can use: Text("\\(pro)") etc...

Comment: I missed '\' in my post I know. My code has '\'.  I used second method but still in vain. The error message is the same.

Comment: edit the question, and show us the code you are using

Comment: I've updated the code. Only that the 'decode([Post2].self' remain the same cause I got error if I remove the '[ ]'.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a possible approach. Hope it helps.